# Spring Boot Narayana for 2-phase commit/XA in Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot

We are exploring using Spring Boot with Narayana for 2-phase commit/XA transactions in a container with PostgreSQL as a backing store for the transaction log.

Is Spring Boot expected to continue Narayana integration in the future?